# glyphicons and some bootstrap features are not working in ASP .net core 3.1 version

Tags: bootstrap-4, glyphicons, asp.net-core-3.1, .net-core-3.1

I'm new to ASP .net core. and I'm developing an application using .net core 3.1 version where it shows the bootstrap version as v4.3.1. but it doesn't work some features in bootstrap such as glyphicon, btn-default, etc.

Comment: `glyphicon` is not available in Bootstrap 4.x https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/migration/#components

Comment: `btn-default` is not available in Bootstrap 4.x, use `btn-primary` instead https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/buttons/

Comment: It looks like Bootstrap 4 doesn't ship the >>Glyphicons Halflings<< set anymore, but check this link: [it is a work around](https://www.ryadel.com/en/bootstrap-3-glyphicons-halflings-set-bootstrap4-fontawesome/)